# How much time left on Windows Server 2008 Evaluation

Tags: windows-server-2008, evaluation

How can you get the server to tell you how much time is left on a Windows Server 2008 evaluation installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the `Slmgr.vbs` script that is in the System32 folder. Use the -dli switch to run this script:

```
slmgr.vbs -dli
```

The command displays the number of days that are left in the current 60-day evaluation period.

Source: [Microsoft Support article 948472 - How to extend the Windows Server 2008 evaluation period](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B948472)

Comment: I have to wait until this evening to try it, but look for the green check mark sometime before UTC midnight (bust the cap!) if it works :)

Comment: Thanks Joel! But it's not a problem. I will not reach the cap today. I like moderating more than hunting for points at the moment.

Comment: I said: "at the moment." ;-)